# forkpty works for some terminal apps, not for others

Tags: linux, c++11, fork, pty, termios

I'm trying to write a pty I/O transparent filter for a shell.

The following example mostly works. Most programs run as expected with the wrapper. This example does not do any filtering, it's purpose is just to provide a framework.

**EDIT**: With my answer below I got this example working. I've updated the example here to reflect that.

Here is the now working code:

```
/*
This example is public domain. Use as you see fit.

The purpose of this example is show how a process can run a shell transparently and be able to filter it's input and output.
This example does not show off any I/O filtering, it only provides the framework on which that could be added.

Tested only on GNU/Linux with recent kernels and recent g++ and clang++

This example is based on original found here:
https://www.scriptjunkie.us/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/stdioterminallogger.c

There were 2 problems with the code this example was based on.
1) Terminal (re)sizing was not being handled
2) Some applications display incorrectly or keys don't work
   a) with 'joe', Enter, Ctrl-M, and Ctrl-J don't work
   b) 'joe' has display isues
   c) 'snake' (game) has display issues

Also, be aware of this:
    #define LOGFILELOCATION "/tmp/.shlog"
in the original code, not this example.

This example does not write produce any files. (intermediate or otherwise)


The following programs do seem to work correctly:
vi, vim, nano, mcedit, htop, top

#1 has been solved with a resize handler (see handler and handleTerminalResize)


Use this in shell's profile/bashrc to indicate pty-filter is present
[ "${inptyfilter}" == "true" ] && PS1="(pty-filter) ${PS1}"

Compile with any of the following:

g++ -std=c++11 pty-filter.cpp  -lutil -o pty-filter
g++ -std=c++1y pty-filter.cpp  -lutil -o pty-filter
g++ -std=c++1z pty-filter.cpp  -lutil -o pty-filter
clang++ -std=c++11 pty-filter.cpp  -lutil -o pty-filter
clang++ -std=c++1y pty-filter.cpp  -lutil -o pty-filter
clang++ -std=c++1z pty-filter.cpp  -lutil -o pty-filter

# for stricter compilation:
clang++ -std=c++1z pty-filter.cpp -lutil -o pty-filter -Wall -Werror -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-disabled-macro-expansion -Wno-vla-extension -Wno-vla

*/

// standard C stuff
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <csignal>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdarg>

// C++ stuff
#include <string>

// Everything else
#include <pty.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// shared globals
struct sharedBookT {
    pid_t childPid;
    pid_t parentPid;
    pid_t shellPid;
    int shellFd;
    termios oldTerm, newTerm, shellTerm;
    bool readyToQuit;
    char fromTerminalBuffer [4096];
    char toTerminalBuffer [4096];
    char padding [3];
};


// avoid non C++ casts (when used with stricter compilation)
typedef const char* constCharPtrT;
typedef void* voidPtr;
typedef sharedBookT* sharedBookPtrT;

static sharedBookPtrT sharedBookPtr = 0;

// sprintf for std::string
std::string Sprintf (const char* fmt, ...) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)));
std::string Sprintf (const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start (ap, fmt);
    const auto n = vsnprintf (0, 0, fmt, ap);
    va_end (ap);

    char result [n+2];

    va_start (ap, fmt);
    vsnprintf (result, size_t (n+1), fmt, ap);
    va_end (ap);

    return std::string (result);
}

// c_str and length shortcut operators for std::string
const char* operator* (const std::string& s) { return s.c_str (); }
size_t operator+ (const std::string& s) { return s.length (); }

// resize shell's pty and notifiy chell of change
void handleTerminalResize () {
    sharedBookT& shared = *sharedBookPtr;
    winsize ws;
    ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws);
    ioctl(shared.shellFd, TIOCSWINSZ, &ws);
    sigqueue (shared.shellPid, SIGWINCH, {0});
}

// log signal, for convience just to stdout
void logsignal (int signal) {
    // can't reliably use regular printf from a signal handler
    const auto msg = Sprintf ("Got signal %d\n", signal);
    write (1, *msg, +msg);
}

// common signal handler
void handler(int signal, siginfo_t * infoP, void *context __attribute__ ((unused))) {
    const auto& si = *infoP;
    const auto myPid = getpid ();

    sharedBookT& shared = *sharedBookPtr;

    // using SIGUSR to notify processes of termination
    // (processes must check for it after blocking syscalls)
    if (signal == SIGUSR2) { // Notification to quit
        shared.readyToQuit = true;
        return;
    }

    auto cc = char (-1);
    if (myPid == shared.parentPid) {
        // only parent process should handle these
        // if child processes handle these as well, there are multiple insertions
        switch (si.si_signo) {
            case SIGINT: cc = 0x03; break;  // "Ctrl-C"
            case SIGTSTP: cc = 0x1A; break; // "Ctrl-Z"
            case SIGQUIT: cc = 0x1C; break; // "Ctrl-\"
            case SIGWINCH: handleTerminalResize (); break;
            default: logsignal (signal); break;
        }
    }
    // write control character (if any) to shell's pty
    if (-1 < cc) write(shared.shellFd, &cc, 1);
}

// Add common signal handler for each signal
void setupsignal(int signal) {
    struct sigaction act;
    sigaction(signal, NULL, &act);
    act.sa_sigaction = handler;
    act.sa_flags |= SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(signal, &act, NULL);
}

// launch shell with new pty
void launchShell () {
    sharedBookT& shared = *sharedBookPtr;
    tcgetattr(0, &shared.shellTerm);

    const auto pid = forkpty(&shared.shellFd, NULL, &shared.shellTerm, NULL);
    if (pid == -1 || pid == 0) {
        if (pid == 0) {
            shared.shellPid = getpid ();
            // inform shell it's pty is being filtered
            setenv ("inptyfilter", "true", 1);
            exit(execlp("/bin/bash", "bash", NULL));
        }
        else {
            perror ("forkpty failed");
            exit (1);
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    // create shared globals structure
    sharedBookPtr = sharedBookPtrT (mmap (
        NULL, sizeof (sharedBookT),
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
        MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0
    ));

    sharedBookT& shared = *sharedBookPtr;

    launchShell ();
    shared.parentPid = getpid ();

    //Set up handler for signals
    setupsignal(SIGINT);
    setupsignal(SIGTSTP);
    setupsignal(SIGUSR1);
    setupsignal(SIGUSR2);
    setupsignal(SIGQUIT);
    setupsignal(SIGWINCH);
    //setupsignal(SIGTTIN);
    //setupsignal(SIGTTOU);

    // fork to handle output to the terminal
    if (0 == fork ()) {
        shared.childPid = getpid ();

        // loop while reading and echoing the pty's output
        for (;;) {
            // read from Shell's Pty
            const auto charsRead = read (shared.shellFd, shared.toTerminalBuffer, sizeof (shared.toTerminalBuffer));

            // if characters were read, echo them and continue
            if (0 < charsRead) {
                write (1, shared.toTerminalBuffer, size_t (charsRead));
                continue;
            }

            // if error, check if we are done            
            if ((charsRead == -1) and (errno == EIO)) {
                fprintf (stderr, "\nterminating I/O processes\r\n");
                // signal parent to exit
                sigqueue (shared.parentPid, SIGUSR2, {0});
                break;
            }
        }

        fprintf (stderr, "Exiting pty-filter (toTerminal)\r\n");
        exit (0);
    }

    // wait for pids to be updated
    while ((0 == shared.shellPid) or (0 == shared.childPid)) usleep (1);

    fprintf (stderr, "parent: %d\n", shared.parentPid);
    fprintf (stderr, "shell: %d\n", shared.shellPid);
    fprintf (stderr, "child: %d\n", shared.childPid);

    tcgetattr(0, &shared.oldTerm); // Disable buffered I/O and echo mode for pty
    shared.newTerm = shared.oldTerm;
    cfmakeraw (&shared.newTerm);
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &shared.newTerm);

    // shell needs intial sizing
    handleTerminalResize ();

    for (;;) {//loop while processing input from pty
        const auto charsRead = read (0, shared.fromTerminalBuffer, sizeof (shared.fromTerminalBuffer));
        // SIGUSR1 will drop process out of read so flag can be read
        if (shared.readyToQuit) {
            fprintf (stderr, "Exiting pty-filter (fromTerminal)\r\n");
            break;
        }

        // in we got input from the terminal, pass it on to the shell's pty
        if (0 < charsRead) {
            write (shared.shellFd, shared.fromTerminalBuffer, size_t (charsRead));
            continue;
        }

        // if error check if we are done
        // However, this is never executed, child fork terminates first
        if ((charsRead == -1) and (errno == EIO)) break;
    }

    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &shared.oldTerm); //reset terminal

    // wait for child forks to exit
    for (;;) {
        auto wpid = wait (0);
        if (wpid == -1) break;
        fprintf (stderr, "%d is done\n", wpid);
    }
    perror ("status");
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, what am I missing? What would cause some programs (like joe and snake) to display erratically, while many other programs (like vi, vim, nano, mcedit, htop, top) seem to work just fine.

(On my system joe and snake work just fine without the "pty filter".)

**EDIT**: As stated above, it now works

Answer (score 1):

Replacing this:

```
shared.newTerm.c_lflag &= tcflag_t (~ICANON);
shared.newTerm.c_lflag &= tcflag_t (~ECHO);
```

with this:

```
shared.newTerm.c_lflag &= tcflag_t (~(ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN | ECHO));
shared.newTerm.c_iflag &= tcflag_t (~(BRKINT | ICRNL | IGNBRK | IGNCR | INLCR | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON | PARMRK));
shared.newTerm.c_oflag &= tcflag_t (~OPOST);
shared.newTerm.c_cc[VMIN] = 1; // 1 char at a time input
shared.newTerm.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
```

made it start working correctly. However, this seems like it should not have any effect, as this is being done on stdin:

```
shared.newTerm.c_oflag &= tcflag_t (~OPOST);
```

**EDIT**: The following post answers the question about stdin vs stdout for tcsetattr.

[When setting terminal attributes via tcsetattr(fd.....), can fd be either stdout or stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873843/when-setting-terminal-attributes-via-tcsetattrfd-can-fd-be-either-stdout)

But anyways, it works now. I will update my original post to reflect this.

**EDIT**: This post was marked as related: [Using the linux pseudo terminal API for multiple debug terminals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557522/using-the-linux-pseudo-terminal-api-for-multiple-debug-terminals?rq=1)
While the answer was not on that post, it pointed to a site that had the information I needed: http://www.man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/tty/tty_functions.c.html

**EDIT**: Replacing the above with the following also works. I will update my original post accordingly.:

```
cfmakeraw (&shared.newTerm);
```

Comment: Replacing your `execlp` to run `nano` makes Ctrl+Z not seem to work for me. I just get the usual _Use "fg" to return to nano._ message, but I don't get a shell prompt back and typing `fg` or Ctrl+C does nothing. Any ideas?